# How to add and import .jar files in android stduio

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I am following this link: **http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/#project-structure**  to add the soap service in my project. I need to add this file: **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies** in my project.

So my question is how can I add the above .jar file in my project to avoid the red highlighted errors in the image below?. Thanks in advance

Error Image:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tell the gradle script to compile your jar file?

you can follow this link
[Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Simply add this line in your app gradle

```
implementation files('libs/ksoap2_3.6.3.jar')
```

Comment: just write implementation files('libs/your_jar_file.jar') why you refer the link